Correct way to join in order to compare 2 tables
I have 2 queries like this:
SELECT * 
FROM ZPAY_VIEW_ACTIVITIES_TO_TABLEAU
WHERE SUBSTRING([CC Receiver], 1, 2) = 'BN'
  AND YEAR(Date) = 2024
  AND pupuk_type = 'CPD-HIK'
  AND SUBSTRING(unique_identity, 3, 1) != '3'
  AND [Employee Code] = '0056263'
  AND Date = '2024-07-12';

and this is the output



Date
Mandor Code
Employee Code
Employee Name
BLOCK_LAPANGAN




2024-07-12
0059326
0056263
EMILIANA RANYE
Q29


2024-07-12
0059326
0056263
EMILIANA RANYE
P39


2024-07-12
0059326
0056263
EMILIANA RANYE
S21


2024-07-12
0059326
0056263
EMILIANA RANYE
S31



another query:
SELECT * 
FROM [elhm_bpn_2024]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Afdeling SKU], 3, 1) != '3'
  AND [Employee Code] = '0056263'
  AND Tanggal = '2024-07-12';

with the output:



Tanggal
Employee Code
Blok




2024-07-12
0056263
P39


2024-07-12
0056263
Q29


2024-07-12
0056263
S22


2024-07-12
0056263
S30



The objective is I want to compare both tables and find out whether BLOCK_LAPANGAN = Blok on the same employee code and date.
As an internal audit team, I came up with 2 conditions:
'Normal' if BLOCK_LAPANGAN = Blok on the same date and employee code
'Anomali' with note 'Blok' if Blok != BLOCK_LAPANGAN on the same date and employee code,
As you can see based on the example employee code, it should be both normal because the block = BLOCK_LAPANGAN
Based on the example, I come up with the query:
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM ZPAY_VIEW_ACTIVITIES_TO_TABLEAU
    WHERE SUBSTRING([CC Receiver], 1, 2) = 'BN'
      AND YEAR(Date) = 2024
      AND pupuk_type = 'CPD-HIK'
      AND SUBSTRING(unique_identity, 3, 1) != '3'
),
CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [elhm_bpn_2024]
    WHERE SUBSTRING([Afdeling SKU], 3, 1) != '3'
)
SELECT 
    a.[Employee Code] AS SKU_SAP,
    a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN AS block_posting_sap,
    b.Blok AS block_posting_elhm,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.[Employee Name] = b.[Employee Name]
             AND (
                (CASE WHEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN < b.Blok THEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN ELSE b.Blok END) = 
                (CASE WHEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN > b.Blok THEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN ELSE b.Blok END)
             )
             AND a.[Activity Name] = b.[Jenis Pekerjaan]
        THEN 'Normal' 
        ELSE 'Anomali' 
    END AS status_anomaly,
    CASE 
        WHEN a.[Employee Name] != b.[Employee Name]
             AND (CASE WHEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN < b.Blok THEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN ELSE b.Blok END) = 
                 (CASE WHEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN > b.Blok THEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN ELSE b.Blok END)
             AND a.[Activity Name] = b.[Jenis Pekerjaan] 
        THEN 'SKU'

        WHEN a.[Employee Name] = b.[Employee Name]
             AND (CASE WHEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN < b.Blok THEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN ELSE b.Blok END) != 
                 (CASE WHEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN > b.Blok THEN a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN ELSE b.Blok END)
             AND a.[Activity Name] = b.[Jenis Pekerjaan] 
        THEN 'Blok'
    ELSE 'Normal' 
    END AS Note
FROM 
    CTE a
JOIN
    CTE2 b ON a.[Employee Code] = b.[Employee Code]
           AND a.Date = b.Tanggal
WHERE 
    a.[Employee Code] = '0056263'
    AND a.Date = '2024-07-12'
GROUP BY 
    a.[Employee Code], a.[Employee Name], a.Date,                     
    b.[Employee Name], a.BLOCK_LAPANGAN, b.Blok,                     
    a.Estate_Name, a.[Activity Name],
    b.[Jenis Pekerjaan];

But why has the result become like this:



Date
Employee Code
block_posting_sap
block_posting_elhm
status_anomaly
note




2024-07-12
0056263
P39
P39
Normal
Normal


2024-07-12
0056263
Q29
Q29
Normal
Normal


2024-07-12
0056263
Q29
P29
Anomali
Blok


2024-07-12
0056263
P29
Q29
Anomali
Blok



 ID Date    EmployeeCode    Block   ID  Tanggal EmployeeCode    Blok    status_anomaly
1   2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 11  2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 Normal
1   2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 12  2024-07-12  0056263 P39 Anomali
1   2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 13  2024-07-12  0056263 S22 Anomali
1   2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 14  2024-07-12  0056263 S30 Anomali
2   2024-07-12  0056263 P39 11  2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 Anomali
2   2024-07-12  0056263 P39 12  2024-07-12  0056263 P39 Normal
2   2024-07-12  0056263 P39 13  2024-07-12  0056263 S22 Anomali
2   2024-07-12  0056263 P39 14  2024-07-12  0056263 S30 Anomali
3   2024-07-12  0056263 S21 11  2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 Anomali
3   2024-07-12  0056263 S21 12  2024-07-12  0056263 P39 Anomali
3   2024-07-12  0056263 S21 13  2024-07-12  0056263 S22 Anomali
3   2024-07-12  0056263 S21 14  2024-07-12  0056263 S30 Anomali
4   2024-07-12  0056263 S31 11  2024-07-12  0056263 Q29 Anomali
4   2024-07-12  0056263 S31 12  2024-07-12  0056263 P39 Anomali
4   2024-07-12  0056263 S31 13  2024-07-12  0056263 S22 Anomali
4   2024-07-12  0056263 S31 14  2024-07-12  0056263 S30 Anomali

You can see there's 2 normal and 14 anomaly hence it should be only 2 normal and 2 anomaly because I already make it in inner join.
Expected result :



Date
Employee Code
block_posting_sap
block_posting_elhm
status_anomaly
note




2024-07-12
0056263
P39
P39
Normal
Normal


2024-07-12
0056263
Q29
Q29
Normal
Normal


2024-07-12
0056263
S21
S22
Anomali
Blok


2024-07-12
0056263
S31
S30
Anomali
Blok



OR



Date
Employee Code
block_posting_sap
block_posting_elhm
status_anomaly
note




2024-07-12
0056263
P39
P39
Normal
Normal


2024-07-12
0056263
Q29
Q29
Normal
Normal


2024-07-12
0056263
S31
S22
Anomali
Blok


2024-07-12
0056263
S21
S30
Anomali
Blok



the main objective is to tell combination that met, and not met (Anomaly)
What is wrong with my query?

In order for others to help you, please provide the sample data in consumable format (DDL, DML). In your final query there are column name like Estate_Name and others that are not in the sample data that you have shown.

You have 2 rows of the same Employee and Date in both of the tables, you will get 4 rows back in result when you JOIN on DATE and Employee Code. How do you relate a row in CTE and another row in CTE2 ? Is there another column / information that you are missing ?

in my real case, what i want to check is for the same Employee Code  on the same Date not only about the Block that i want to check, but any other column e.g. the activity and the employee name. but since the problem are appear when i check the Block similarity, i only provide on this question anything related to the Block information.

The reason you get 4 rows instead of 2 is because, for each row in CTE1, there are 2 matching rows (based on the JOIN condition DATE & EmployeeCode), see this simplified fiddle example

Thanks for the fiddle, back to the objective, what i want is to check whether from employee code and date are the block is similar or not, based on my example it should be 2 data because both from tables are 2 record, and i want to compare the block
but if i put  c1.BLOK = c2.BLOCK_LAPANGAN on the join side
Then for some case if employee code input the wrong code, it can't be traced

with reference to my fiddle, for table CTE1 ID = 1, should you compare with ID = 11 or 12 on CTE2 ? How do you decide which row to compare to ? based on what ?

the objective is if employee code on the same day has different block, then it should be anomaly,
example :
if A put the blok A29 and J20
and A appear to be A29 and J21 on the different table (another CTE)
then it should be anomaly on J20 and J21 because the block is not same,
hence it should be 1 Normal (A29 to A29)
and 1 Anomaly (J20 to J21) on the same date and employee code

but there are two rows on the same day, one with same and another with different block. (Q29 and P39), so it should consider as anamaly or normal ?

based on the fiddle and example case, it should considered as 2 normal because on the same employee code and the same date, the employee input the same block (q29 to q29, and p39 to p39)

thanks for the help and explanation, that is still what i've been looking for, how to manage the combination or table or the order so the query will compare to every block within the same day and employee code. i need to get the order, or the join scheme that can compare the combination of block within the same employee code and date

Thanks for the fiddle, back to the objective, what i want is to check whether from employee code and date are the block is similar or not, based on my example it should be 2 data because both from tables are 2 record, and i want to compare the block but if i put c1.BLOK = c2.BLOCK_LAPANGAN on the join side Then for some case if employee code input the wrong code, it can't be traced.
example if my block on C1 are p90 and block on C2 are n90
then the data is not appear because we join that based on block, hence it should identify as 'Anomaly'  (p90 to n90)

i just adding with your fiddle and code on this https://dbfiddle.uk/u9cBIXtQ
thank you very much for the help, how to display  or add column c2.block so i know which block are different. on this case (fiddle) i know S21 is Abnormal because on cte2 that is S22

i already did that on my expected result, i just posted block_posting_sap (CTE1) and block_posting_elhm (CTE2)

if 2 record are completely different, then all of the combination are anomaly, if there's 3 record, and the combination are not the same at all, then whatever the combination as long as the anomaly are 3 record, it should be fine

i already did the expected result, as you can see, block_posting_sap are block in CTE1, and block_posting_elhm are block in CTE2

ah i see, you ask if there's any abnormal case, ok let me add it, thank you very much

i see, the case is that to check if employee code input the same block for both tables, both tables are coming from different system on the business real case, i know this is need another column, but on the real case, there's not any key but date and employee code, do you think this is impossible to solve the case?

i see, the main problem is when i tried to compare both sources, i just realize sometimes the employee input more than 1 row on the same day, and  there's no unique column other than employee code and date itself, i need to rethink how to solve this kind of situation

Like all things SQL, you need to have clear logical requirements before you attempt a query. SQL can only implement logic you specify. So if you can't come up with a logical way to solve the problem, you certainly can't write a query that magically solves it.
That said, based on everything you've said, here is a possible solution... its terrible, and fragile, but it might just work.

Matching rows are easy, we just check whether a matching row exists, and if so call it 'Normal'. Of course if there was a different number of matching rows in each table then this fails straight away.

Then we allocate a row number to the invalid rows of each table, and we use this row number to pull an unused, invalid Block/Blok code from the other table. This depends on having a unique ordering sequence, I've used the Block/Blok code for this, but if it isn't unique then this method will fail.


Its horribly convoluted, but maybe it does what you need.
with cte11 as (
  select *
    -- If we can find a matching row in the other table, then its 'normal'
    , case when exists (
      select 1
      from CTE2 c2
      where c2.Tanggal = c1.[Date]
      and c2.EmployeeCode = c1.EmployeeCode
      and c2.Blok = c1.Block) then 'Normal' else 'Abnormal' end status_anomaly
  from CTE1 c1
), cte22 as (
  -- Allocate row numbers to all the 'abnormal' rows
  select *
    , row_number() over (partition by EmployeeCode, [Date], status_anomaly order by Block) rn1
  from cte11
)
select *
  -- For all 'abnormal' rows attempt to pull an unused Blok from
  -- the other table, using the row number to ensure we only
  -- use each Blok code once.
  , case when status_anomaly = 'Normal' then Block else (
      select Blok
      from (
        select c2.Blok
          , row_number() over (partition by EmployeeCode, [Date] order by Block) rn2
        from CTE2 c2
        where c2.Tanggal = c1.[Date]
        and c2.EmployeeCode = c1.EmployeeCode
        and c2.Blok not in (select c3.Block from cte22 c3 where c3.status_anomaly = 'Normal')
    ) x
    where x.rn2 = c1.rn1
  ) end
from cte22 c1;

Returns



ID
Date
EmployeeCode
Block
status_anomaly
rn1
(No column name)




3
2024-07-12
0056263
S21
Abnormal
1
S22


4
2024-07-12
0056263
S23
Abnormal
2
S24


2
2024-07-12
0056263
P39
Normal
1
P39


1
2024-07-12
0056263
Q29
Normal
2
Q29



db<>fiddle

Thank you very much for the advice, now i know the real problem is, but the reality is in there, i still find out what column should i add to maximize the process in my job

Another approach
You already have a CTE1 and CTE2 so:

filtering employee and date inside each CTE
Get minimal value Block FROM equal or greater value BlockLapangan
(optional) Extra column show the GAP between

I forced some data for simulate gaps
;WITH TResult
as
(
    SELECT a.*
          ,(SELECT MIN(sb.Block)
              FROM CTE2 sb 
             WHERE sb.Block >= a.BlockLapangan
        ) AS Block
        , LEAD(a.BlockLapangan,1) OVER (ORDER BY a.BlockLapangan) AS NextBlockLapangan
    FROM CTE1 a
)
SELECT   EmployeeCode
        ,RecordDate
        ,BlockLapangan
        ,Block
        ,(SELECT STRING_AGG(Block,',')
              FROM CTE2 sb 
             WHERE Block > BlockLapangan 
               AND Block < NextBlockLapangan
        ) AS Gap
        ,IIF(Block = BlockLapangan,'Normal','Anomali') AS Status_Anomaly    
        ,IIF(Block = BlockLapangan,'Normal','Block') AS Note    
FROM TResult
ORDER BY BlockLapangan

Complete solution

The problem with this method (i did consider it) is that it only works if the order of block is such that the normal rows all end up with matching row numbers. As soon as a non-matchibf block changes the order, you can miss matching rows

Oh, thank you @DaleK you absolutely right. I changed for resolve the GAP

Now you're not returning the abnormal block mismatch, which is a requirement :) its definitely not an easy problem.

do you know what is the Gap for? sorry im still new and beginner, because gap is in there when status is normal and anomali so i don't know what's the Gap for

Hi @FachryDzaky.  What i mean about GAP is something RANGE GAP.If you have tableA values 1,4,5 and tableB 1,2,3,4,5 the GAP will be 2 and 3, but 1,4 and 5 are Normal (same employe code + date)
